# Output HTML Table in Django For Each Date in SQL Query

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am creating a call reports dashboard in django, and I want to output a postgresql Select query in an HTML table for each date of the month like this:
[image]

And this is the output that I am receiving. It is just giving me totals for each extension for the month in each table instead of the total for that distinct date. I tried to change the query to

[image]

For whatever reason I am having a very hard time figuring this out. This is my HTML, I know I am not doing the looping right here, I've just been running out of ideas.

```
    {% for i in lt.itertuples %}
            
           <table class="table" style="float:left">
            <caption>{{ i.to_date }}</caption>
            <thead>
             
                <tr>
            
                <th>Extension</th>
                <th>Calls</th>
             </tr>
            </thead>
            {% for d in df4.itertuples %}
            <tr>
               
                <td>
                    {{ d.member_extension }}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{ d.count }}
                </td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
         </table>
         {% endfor %} 
       
        </div>
```

And this is a snippet of my Python:

```
query=pd.read_sql_query("select DISTINCT date(start_date) as 'DATE()' from Reports3; ",con3)
query2=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT COUNT(*),member_extension from Reports3 group by member_extension ",con3)

df4 = pd.DataFrame(query)
lt = pd.DataFrame(query2)

ext4=pd.unique(df4['member_extension'])

context={'df4':df4, 'ex4':ext4, 'lt':lt }
return render(request,'index2.html',context)
```

I tried changing the Query to:
`SELECT DISTINCT TO_DATE(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD'), COUNT(*),member_extension from Reports3 group by member_extension,TO_DATE(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') ORDER BY TO_DATE(start_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')`

And that outputs this result:
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is going wrong with your above approach, for example can you add a screenshot to explain what's missing.

Comment: No problem, I added the two results that I have been receiving.